# How to construct an open interval for $V_n'$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

Taken from the Munkres book  page no :$ 333$

Theorem $53.1$: The  map $p : \mathbb{R} \to S^1$  given by  equation $ p(x)= ( \cos 2 \pi x  , \sin 2 \pi x) $is covering map

In proof  munkres say that  $p^{-1}(U)=\{ x \in \mathbb{R} | \cos 2 \pi x >0\}=\bigcup V_n= \cup_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} ( n -1/4, n+1/4)$

in second paragraph again Munkres  say that  similar  argument  can be applied to the intersection  of $S^1$  with the upper and lower  open half plane , and with the open left hand half plane

Now let denote  $U'$ be the open left half plane

$p^{-1}(U')=\{ x \in \mathbb{R} | \cos 2 \pi x <0\}=\bigcup V_n'=???$

Now my question is that   how to construct an open interval  for $V_n'$

Actually  im not able construct an open interval for $p^{-1}(U')$

Comment: How is $U$ defined?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net $U$ is  a subset  of $S^1$ consisting  of those points having  positive  first coordinates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be getting
$$p^{-1}(U') = \bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{Z}} (n+\frac{1}{4}, n+\frac{3}{4}) = \bigcup V_n$$

It seems you just to see when $\cos (x)$ is positive and negative. Observe that $\cos(2\pi x)$ is periodic at the integers. Find an interval of largest length for which $\cos (2\pi x)$ is positive and then do the same for when $\cos(2\pi x)$ is negative. Then just translate these by the integers.

E.g $\cos(2\pi x) > 0$ for $x \in (-\frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{4})$ and
$\cos(2\pi x) < 0$ for $x \in (\frac{1}{4}, \frac{3}{4})$

Comment: Got  its now , actually this interval didn't click  in my mind.I think my  I.Q level is very low

Answer (score 0):

Take $${V_n'}={\left(n-\frac12,n+\frac12\right)}$$and that $x\in\left(n-\frac12,n+\frac12\right)\iff2\pi x\in\left(2\pi n-\pi,2\pi n+\pi\right)$.

$p^{-1}(U')=\{ x \in \mathbb{R} | \cos 2 \pi x <0\}=\bigcup V_n'=\bigcup{\left(n-\frac12,n+\frac12\right)}$

Comment: Just from what you've written in the question, you can see this doesn't work. $p^{-1}(U)$ should be disjoint from $p^{-1}(U')$. But your $V_n$ and $V'_n$ both contain $n$.

Comment: oks let me think more  @DionelJaime